# Referencing the same table both as target of UPDATE and source of data in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql-update, subquery

I wanted to make an update against my local database where I'd make some of the fields have the same value as another field present in the table.

I came up with this query:

```
$wpdb->prepare(
    "
    UPDATE wp_usermeta meta
    SET meta.meta_value = (
      SELECT usermeta.meta_value
      FROM wp_usermeta usermeta
      WHERE usermeta.meta_key='nickname'
      AND usermeta.user_id = %d
    )
    WHERE meta.user_id = %d
    AND meta.meta_key='first_name'
    ",
    $userId[0],
    $userId[0]
)
```

The query would be run in a PHP loop so on each iteration the `$userId` will be different. The query is run against WordPress database (but this should be irrelevant to the question).

I'm receiving the following error when attempting to run the query:

> Table 'meta' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as
>   a separate source for data

How could I solve this problem?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

One method is to use `join` instead:

```
UPDATE wp_usermeta meta JOIN
       wp_usermeta meta2
       on meta.user_id = meta2.user_id and
          meta2.meta_key = 'nickname'
SET meta.meta_value = meta2.meta_value
WHERE meta.user_id = %d AND meta.meta_key = 'first_name';
```

I might suggest adding something to the `where` clause such as `meta.meta_value is not null`, just in case the first name is already populated.  However, you seem to want to copy the field, which is what the above does.

Comment: Oh, you beat me to it

Comment: This is great thank you. Only small change `meta2 = 'nickname'` should be `meta2.meta_key='nickname'`.

Comment: Can `UPDATE wp_usermeta meta JOIN` be translated into `UPDATE wp_usermeta AS meta JOIN`? This is in fact a labeling right?

Comment: @71GA . . . You can use `as` for table aliases.  I don't, but you can if you like.

Comment: Very nice solution !

Answer (score 2):

```
 UPDATE wp_usermeta x
   JOIN wp_usermeta y
     ON y.user_id = x.user_id 
    SET x.meta_value = y.meta_value
  WHERE y.meta_key = 'nickname'
    AND x.meta_key = 'first_name'
    AND x.user_id = %d;
```