# MySQL - incrementing a column value based on COUNT

Tags: mysql

I have this table:

[image]

Now if I count rows in column `id_racuna` that are not `NULL` using:

```
SELECT COUNT (id_racuna) FROM racuni WHERE id_racuna IS NOT NULL;
```

I get:

[image]

So if I use this value in an update like this:

```
UPDATE racuni AS r1 JOIN racuni AS r2 ON r1.id_interesa = r2.id_interesa
SET r1.id_racuna = (SELECT COUNT (r2.id_racuna) FROM r2 WHERE r2.id_racuna IS NOT NULL) +1,
    r1.poslano = curdate()
WHERE r1.id_interesa = 8;
```

I would expect to get:

[image]

but I get an error:

> Table r2 doesn't exist!

I tried to trick MySQL using `JOIN` to think that `r1` and `r2` are two different tables, but it doesn't work. I have seen this kind of trick [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35711343/referencing-the-same-table-both-as-target-of-update-and-source-of-data-in-mysql) where it worked... What am I missing?

---

**UPDATE:**

I need to use `JOIN` because if I wrote just:

```
UPDATE racuni
SET id_racuna = (SELECT COUNT (id_racuna) FROM racuni WHERE id_racuna IS NOT NULL) +1,
    poslano = curdate()
WHERE id_interesa = 8;
```

I would get error:

> Table 'racuni' is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as
>   a separate source for data

Comment: I mean you're referring to two tables as r2. Maybe try without that to see where MySQL is unhappy?

Comment: If I leave it out, I would get error: Table is specified twice, both as a target for 'UPDATE' and as a separate source for data.

Comment: Oh I see. Well why not set a variable equal to the value of the count, then run your straightforward update query below?

Comment: Below is related to MySQL update join syntax:

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1262786/mysql-update-query-based-on-select-query

Comment: based on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429319/you-cant-specify-target-table-for-update-in-from-clause the follwoing should also work: `UPDATE racuni SET id_racuna = (SELECT * FROM (SELECT COUNT(id_racuna) FROM racuni) as t);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with a cross join and wrap your sub query in it

```
UPDATE racuni AS r1 
CROSS JOIN (SELECT COUNT (id_racuna) id_racunacount 
    FROM racuni 
    WHERE id_racuna IS NOT NULL) a
SET r1.id_racuna = a.id_racunacount + 1,
    r1.poslano = curdate()
WHERE r1.id_interesa = 8;
```

Comment: This works! Could you please explain why my solution didn't work and why your works?

Comment: Because you are using the same table directly in `SET` clause while in mine you can see i calculated count in sub select and used a cross join to make a separate data set and gave an alias as `a` this way you can do an update on same table by doing selection from same table

Comment: Wouldn't usage of `JOIN` instead of `CROSS JOIN` execute faster?

Comment: @71GA there is no `ON` clause if you see in query to get some benefit of index, so no i can't say/suggest anything about the execution of query

Comment: So is there a way to make this faster by not using a cross join? When table gets large it might execute slow.

Comment: An index on `id_racuna` would be good because there is a where clause on this column so filtering of nulls will be faster